# EnterActions animations not stopping and ExitActions animations not starting

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, storyboard, datatrigger

one of my company's applications displays pop ups by means of a content control centered on the screen, which is hidden until needed, and a radial gradient rectangle behind it to block the rest of the UI, plus it looks nice. I am trying to add an animation for when both the rectangle and the pop up are displayed, instead of just popping up. The enter animation works good, but the exit animation is never invoked when my pop up is closed, and the effects of the enter animation remain permanent.

My XAML is as follows:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Panel.ZIndex="999" DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static popup:PopUpService.Instance}}" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsPopUpVisible}" Opacity="0">
        <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource RadialBlackToBlack}" />
        <ItemsControl Focusable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding PopUps}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPopUpVisible, Source={x:Static popup:PopUpService.Instance}}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="100" Duration="0:0:1"/>

                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>

                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opacity should animate to `1` not `100`, this causes the problem. (The animation from `100` to `1` is not visible, and the last bit from `1` to `0` gets little animation time)

Maybe you also want to get rid of redundancy:

1. Do not set properties twice or unnecessarily, drop the `Duration` on the `Storyboards` and all the `HoldEnd`s, that is the default.
2. Why is there an `AutoReverse` in the first SB?

Comment: But when IsPopUpVisible becomes false, the trigger conditions are no longer met and the exit animations should fire, shouldn't they? IsPopUpVisible does not make pop ups invisible right away, I intend to do so by means of the exit animation by setting opacity to 0.

Comment: @SoManyGoblins: Edited my answer, i observed some major delay in your code because the animation goes from `100` to `0` and only at `1` a difference can be seen (the valid range is `0` to 1`), but ultimately it did work in making the grid invisible.